# How do I project a single column in JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need to query a table and project only 1 column. In Hibernate Criteria API there is such thing as `Projections` class. But the Hibernate Criteria API is deprecated now and I need to switch to using JPA Criteria API. I know about the following opportunity:

```
cb.construct(EmpMenu.class,
      c.get("name"), c.get("department").get("name"));
```

But the problem is that I need to retrieve 1 property only. In this approach above I would create a dummy object wrapper just for sake of mapping. I would define the needed field there and it will work.

But is there a clearer way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: There are ample docs for selecting a single field in JPA Criteria on the web, for example http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_result_clause

Comment: @Billy Frost oh, my bad, really. simply selecting a path of the property. thank you! post your answer if you'd like to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JPA Criteria docs on the internet to explain that. For example [this one](http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_result_clause). In simple terms you select the path of the field, like this

```
Path nameField = candidateRoot.get(Person_.name);
crit.select(nameField);
```